# ¿Se puede realizar un split en un string sin espacios con expresiones regulares en Java?

Tags: java, regex

Si tengo una entrada de String como el siguiente:

```
String = "11111212";
```

¿Puedo realizar un split donde no exista un espacio con expresiones regular? Tener de salida:

```
1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2
```

Intenté con la expresión `\S+` donde indico que cada vez que no exista un espacio entre mi string realice un split con `.split()` pero no me funcionó. Intenté ahora con un `StringTokenizer` y tampoco me funcionó.

Mi intención es realizar ese split para así agarrar esos valores, convertirlos a un `int` y realizar una suma.

Anexo el código que llevo actualmente:

```
    Matcher mat;
    String str; 
    String delimiter = "\\S";
    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    int X = 10, x = 10, Z = 20, z = 20;
    // [125] Only 1,2 and 5
    // \\d+ Only digits
    // \\S without spaces.
    // 0x30 = 0 && 0x31
    // 0010000 = 10
    // \\S
    //Only 1,2,5,x,X,z,Z values accepted (x or X= 10, z or Z=20)
    //[1-10] only 1-10 digits accepted.
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[125xXzZ]\\S[1-10]"); 
    File file = new File("test.txt"); //Ex: 1111111111 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null)
        values.add(str); //add values on an Array.
    for(int i=0; i<values.size(); i++){
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(values.get(i));
        while(st.hasMoreTokens())
            System.out.println(st.nextToken(delimiter));
        
        mat = pat.matcher(values.get(i));
        if(mat.matches())
            System.out.println("Accepted: "+values.get(i));
        else
            System.out.println("Declined: "+values.get(i));
    }
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr lo que pides debes pasar un `String` vacío como expresión regular.

```
String str = "123";
String[] split = str.split("");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split)) // Output: [1, 2, 3]
```